# Error while retrieving data from Apache spark dataframe : Scala

Tags: scala, memory, apache-spark, dataframe, emr

I have been trying to create a data frame by getting values from a broadcasted map which has id mapped to POJO class object.

```
import com.mapping.data.model.MappingUtils
import com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo


val mappingPathA = "s3://.../"
val mappingPathB = "s3://.../"


val inputA = sc.textFile(mappingPathA)

 val MappingsListA = inputA.map(x => new JSONObject(x)).
      filter(jsonObj => jsonObj.has("itemId") && jsonObj.get("itemId").toString.startsWith("B0")).
      map { jsonObj =>
        val itemId = jsonObj.get("itemId").toString
        val itemType = jsonObj.getJSONObject("item").get("type").toString
        (itemId, itemType)
      }.collectAsMap

val items =  sqlContext.sql("select * from itemList")

val  broadcastedMapA = sc.broadcast(MappingsListA)

broadcastedMapA.value.size = 4619134

items.printSchema
root
 |-- customerId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- countryId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- itemId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- itemType: string (nullable = true)


val getItemType: (String => String) = (itemId: String) => {
    if (broadcastedMapA.value.contains(itemId)) broadcastedMapA.value(itemId) else "Unknown Item"
}

val sqlfunc = udf(getItemType)

val dfA = items.drop("itemType").withColumn("newItemType", sqlfunc(col("itemId")))

dfA.count = 1257827

dfA.printSchema

root
 |-- customerId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- countryId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- itemId: string (nullable = true)
 |-- newItemType: string (nullable = true)

dfA.count = 1257827

dfA.show()  --- works fine. 

dfA.write.parquet("s3://...") -- works fine 



val inputB = sc.textFile(mappingPathB)

val MappingsListB = inputB.map(x=> {
                    val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfoString(x);
                    (countryInfo.getItemId(), countryInfo)
                 }).collectAsMap

MappingsListB: scala.collection.Map[String,com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo] 

val  broadcastedMapB = sc.broadcast(MappingsListB)

broadcastedMapB.value.size = 602921

val itemValue : (String => String) = (newItemType: String) => { 
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(broadcastedMapB.value(newItemType).getItemValue)) broadcastedMapB.value(newItemType).getItemValue  else "unknown"
}

val entityfunc = udf(itemValue)

val dfB = dfA.filter(not($"newItemType" === "Unknown Item")).withColumn("itemValue",entityfunc(col("newItemType")))

dfB.count = 1256770 

dfB.show()
```

gives me error :

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132) at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:84) at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:362) at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:284) at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:191) at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:220) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:205) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:211) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:93) at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:207) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:170) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:304) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


dfB.write.parquet("s3://...")
```

gives me error :

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3332) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:137) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:121) at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:421) at java.lang.StringBuffer.append(StringBuffer.java:272) at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:112) at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:456) at java.io.PrintWriter.write(PrintWriter.java:473) at java.io.PrintWriter.print(PrintWriter.java:603) at java.io.PrintWriter.println(PrintWriter.java:756) at java.lang.Throwable$WrappedPrintWriter.println(Throwable.java:764) at java.lang.Throwable.printEnclosedStackTrace(Throwable.java:695) at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:667) at java.lang.Throwable.printStackTrace(Throwable.java:721) at org.apache.log4j.DefaultThrowableRenderer.render(DefaultThrowableRenderer.java:60) at org.apache.log4j.spi.ThrowableInformation.getThrowableStrRep(ThrowableInformation.java:87) at org.apache.log4j.spi.LoggingEvent.getThrowableStrRep(LoggingEvent.java:413) at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.subAppend(WriterAppender.java:313) at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.append(WriterAppender.java:162) at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.doAppend(AppenderSkeleton.java:251) at org.apache.log4j.helpers.AppenderAttachableImpl.appendLoopOnAppenders(AppenderAttachableImpl.java:66) at org.apache.log4j.Category.callAppenders(Category.java:206) at org.apache.log4j.Category.forcedLog(Category.java:391) at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:856) at org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerAdapter.error(Log4jLoggerAdapter.java:575) at org.apache.spark.Logging$class.logError(Logging.scala:95) at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.logError(LogicalPlan.scala:28) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:154) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:56) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelation.scala:108)
```

Am I doing any thing wrong here ?

I tried this as well :

```
val items = dfA.filter(not($"newGti" === "Unknown GTI")).map(row => {
    val customerId =  row.getAs[String](1);
    val countryId =  row.getAs[String](2);

    val itemId =  row.getAs[String](3);
    val itemType = row.getAs[String](4);

    val itemValue =  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(broadcastedMapB.value(newItemType).getItemValue)) broadcastedMapB.value(newItemType).getItemValue  else "unknown"

    Row(customerId, countryId ,itemId,itemType,itemValue)
})
```

Also gives me the same error.

My Cluster config : EMR 4.3

```
Slaves - 29 master - 1 Type : r3.8xLarge
    spark.driver.cores      20      
    spark.driver.memory     100g
    spark.executor.cores    10
    spark.executor.memory   40g
    spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max   512m
```

Comment: I was running into a similar issue. I suspect it was because the data was blowing the memory on the master. Keep an eye on what's being `collect`ed.

Comment: @Noel Yeah, that why I tried to save and test but still that gives me an error.

Comment: I suspect bringing all that data onto the master itself causes the error. Try trimming down (eg through sampling or filtering) the amount of data being brought to the master.